# Updating table with percent sign in column name

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm connected to a postgresql database with psycopg2. I'm trying to update a column, but the column name has a percent sign in it (that I can't change).

I'm trying to do:

```
QRY = """update X set "foo%" = %s"""
cursor.execute(QRY, some_value)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. psycopg2 gives a bizarre error about list index out of range. How can I properly escape it?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using format strings, like `%s` in yours, you need to use `%%` to get a literal percent sign.

Comment: Ohh, of course. It's *python* that's screwing it up. I'm dumb.